# Using if(!isset to navigate but its displaying multiple pages in 1

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use if (!isset($page)) to navigate through my navbar here is whats in my index.php:

```
    <?php include_once('includes/header/Header.php');?>

    <?php include_once('includes/content/content.php');?> 

    <?php include_once('includes/navbar/IndexNav.php');?> // Mynavbar

<div class="container"> 
<div class="row"> 
<a href="index.php?page=Cata" class="btn btn-block btn-info">Catagories</a>
// etc
```

In my header I have

```
<?php $page = $_GET['page']; ?>
```

As well as meta information etc. Then in my Contents page I'm using:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($page)) {
    include('index.php');
    }
    if ($page == "Home") { 
    include('index.php');
    }
    if ($page == "Cata") { 
    include('cata.php');
    }
 ?>
```

OK so here's where its going wrong. When I visit my index.php my information has been doubled and put below the original information like this

```
-------------------------
| Index.php Information |
-------------------------
-------------------------
| Index.php Information |
-------------------------
```

So it's like 2 pages on 1 page, one below the other. Now, if I navigate to my cata.php It displays like this

```
 -------------------------
| cata.php Information |
-------------------------
-------------------------
| Index.php Information |
-------------------------
```

Why is every page showing the information from my index.php and why is my index.php showing it twice? I'm really confused, thanks to anyone who can help!

EDIT: Issue resolved!
Where I was going wrong: I had the index requiring the Index which created a duplicate copy.
How I fixed it: I moved all the code from my Index.php to a new file called News.php then put my navigation code into my Index.php by itself.

```
    <?php $page = $_GET['page']; 

        if (!isset($page)) {
        include('news.php');
        }
        if ($page == "Home") { 
        include('news.php');
        }
?>
```

Thank you to everyone who participated in helping me, your time was valuable to myself.

Comment: Make sure you are A) not including index below all this code. B) including index in one of the included pages. The code you posted wouldn't cause this, but since this isn't likely all the code, it is pretty much impossible to give you a definite answer and anything we could say is just a guess.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for replying - I've tripled checked everything and nothing of the sort, I also tried clearing all of my code from cata.php and now when I click on it, it only shows the information of the index.php.. so I checked the index again  - I removed the 'include content' piece of code and it fixed the duplicate issue. So surely that's where it is. However this is all of the contents inside content.php http://prntscr.com/7hateo

Comment: so you are visiting the page `index.php`, which includes `content.php` which also includes `index.php`. You are using include_once, so the include of index doesn't include content a second time (this is good, else you would end up with an infinite loop).

Comment: Yes, this is what I am using. What do I need to change?

Comment: Well, it's why your output is being duplicated. The index page is being loaded twice. Once from the page request and again from the include.

Comment: I moved the code from contents.php to my index.php and it fixed the issue. However when I visit my cata.php it's still showing the index information aswell as the cata's information. I removed every line of code from cata.php and replaced it with a simple 'Hello' and it still displays both pages at once. I have tried using ifelse and switch but its the same.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you have to use `elseif`, if you want to check one variable.

```
if (!isset($page)){
  // get index.php
}elseif ($page == 'home'){
  // get index.php
}elseif ($page == 'cata'){
 // get cata.php
}
```

EDIT:
You can create switch too.

```
switch ($page){
  case 'home':
    // get index.php
    break;
  case 'cata':
    // get cata.php
    break;
  default:
    // get ingex.php
}
```

Comment: While `if/elseif` is certainly a step in the right direction. This is probably a better case for a `switch/case` statement.

Comment: Thank you Gustav's, your methods worked perfectly, I just had my code written in the wrong files!